# Android Progress Dialog Spinner not showing

Tags: android, spinner, progressdialog

I have created a class for Progress Dialog just to avoid rewriting few line of code. Please check the code below.

```
public class AppProgressDialog {

/**
 * progress dialog object 
 */
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/**
 * stores is progress dialog is cancellable 
 */
private boolean isProgressDialogCancelable = false;

/**
 * style of progress dialog
 */
private int progressDialogStyle = ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER;

/**
 * true if progress time not known
 */
private boolean isIndetermined = true;

/**
 * constructor to initialize this custom progress dialog class
 * @param activity activity to which this progress dialog will belong
 * @param message Message to be shown inside progress dialog
 */
public AppProgressDialog(Activity activity) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(isProgressDialogCancelable);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(isIndetermined);
}

/**
 * function to set display message inside progress dialog
 * @param message string to be shown inside progress dialog 
 */
public void setProgressDialogMessage(String message)
{
    if (progressDialog!=null) {
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    }
}

/**
 * function to show progress dialog
 */
public void showProgressDialog()
{
    if (progressDialog!=null) {
        if(!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }
}

/**
 * function to hide progress dialog
 */
public void dismissProgressDialog()
{
    if (progressDialog!=null) {
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using it in a Fragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

private AppProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static TestFragment newInstance() {

    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new AppProgressDialog(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    Button btnTest = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new TestAsyncTask().execute();

        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setProgressDialogMessage("Logging you to eventizon");
        progressDialog.showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismissProgressDialog();
    }

}
```

}

Now, the problem is I am not able to see the spinner which is usually seen in a Progress Dialog. I am testing this on Lollipop.

Comment: How do you use this class

Comment: AppProgressDialog progressDialog = new AppProgressDialog(getActivity()); //use "getActivity()" if using inside a fragment or use "this" if using inside an 
activity
progressDialog.setProgressDialogMessage("message"); //set message
progressDialog.showProgressDialog(); //show dialog
progressDialog.dismissProgressDialog(); //hide dialog

Comment: Usually this problem is because you're doing heavy work on the UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and show the dialog on `onPreExecute`, do your work inside `doInBackground` and dismiss the dialog `onPostExecute`. Also any `View` related code like changing images on `ImageView`, changing text on `TextView` must happen on `onPostExecute`.

Comment: The only heavy work I am doing is scaling a bitmap and setting it as a background image for parent layout of the fragment. I removed it and tried didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the progress dialog in UI thread,So in your AsyncTask preExecute method do like below,

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new AppProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    progressDialog.setProgressDialogMessage("Logging you to eventizon");
                    progressDialog.showProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
```

and onPostExecute dismiss the dialog.

Comment: yes, actually i am doing this inside a fragment so I am using getActivity() instead of this

Comment: and what parent theme you are using

Comment: can you show more of your code snippets, I tested your given code it is working

Comment: are you able to see the spinner inside progress dialog?

Comment: yes, unless you show your code it would be very difficult to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87546/discussion-between-pritam-kadam-and-amar).